# What is the best way to detect the Content-Type of a Node response?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have a connect middleware which conditionally manipulates a Node response. Generally I do not want to manipulate these responses unless they're HTML (note that the responses themselves are proxies of other resources and may be anything) especially because my middleware overloads `writeHead` and `write` and `end` in order to insert some transform logic. Originally it seemed like `res.getHeader('Content-Type')` would be the right approach but it turns out this is almost always `undefined`. Instead I'm now looking at the `req.headers.accept` value and then attempting to test it with `/^text\/html*./.test(accept)`. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called [Content sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) or MIME sniffing.

*Before you do any sniffing, you should aware of the security issues that can arise if you incorrectly identify the content type.*

The [WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) has a [MIME Sniffing Standard](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/), but I have not found a node.js package that implements it.

You may find [doc-sniff](https://github.com/bitinn/doc-sniff) useful (but I have not used it).

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't seem like there's a way to use doc-sniff in a streaming context, right?